# JSON.Net Schema support for OpenAPI 3 specific keywords, specifically "discriminator"?

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

[OpenAPI v3.0.3](https://swagger.io/specification/) supports some keywords in the request/response bodies that are non-standard JSONSchema keywords, one in particular being the [discriminator](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) keyword for polymorphism support.

Just curious if [JSON.Net Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) supports validating against this (and other) non-standard JSONSchema keywords.

I noticed that [the demo](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) allows for selection of "openapi.json" as the schema, but I think that's just for validating that the input is a correctly-defined OpenAPI document rather than actual validation of a request/response payload that accommodates those non-standard keywords.

Comment: If you leave a downvote, leave a comment...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `descriminator` doesn't effect validation. It's only used by things like code generators.

Comment: I concur based on my reading of the spec 3.0.3 document. The spec only talks about `discriminator` in terms of informing applications about the instance, not anything about changing the validation result.